# Do we still need a Remember Me button on websites? Or can we rely on modern browsers to handle this?

Tags: website-design, user-expectation, web-app, login

I recently had a discussion at work about whether to include a "Remember Me" option on our website. Altough I was initially in favour of the idea, I later realised that most browsers already provide such functionality. So I was wondering if it's still necessary to include this option in 2018. What do you think?

Comment: It depends on user privacy in the site. Better not to ask in payment sites. I have checked remember me in Facebook and Twitter and LinkedIn so that I don't have to login Everytime.

Answer (score 9):

Browsers can remember your details, yes. However the Remember Me option caters for the opposite situation - users on shared machines. A website will be configured to intentionally *not* remember the users details, *unless* they choose the 'Remember Me' option.

That way, people checking their Facebook in a public library won't have to clear their browser cache when their session finishes (because most people won't do that).

So, is it necessary to include a 'Remember Me' option? That depends on your application. Is it only ever going to be used on private users machines (such as a work application) or is it something likely to be used on shared, public machines (library, home computer etc).

Comment: I wonder whether providing the opposite action ("Automatically log me out after this session" or some such) would be a better design?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers do not provide this functionality. A browser may store credentials, but you have to manually press "login" each time.

The advantage of a remember me button is, that a user does not need to login every time he closes the browser. For example, in Gmail, Facebook, Netflix, Twitter, LinkedIn etc. one does not need to login each time one open the page (if one uses the remember me button). If would drive me crazy, if I had to login on each of these pages.

On the other hand, on my local outdated library website I have to click each time the "Login" butten. When I close the browser I am logged out again. I hate this additional click, a remember me button is not offered:
[image]

So in my opinion, a remember-me button is absolutely necessary.